# Code a Excel SQL into VBA - Connection string issue

Tags: sql-server, vba, connection-string

I have multiple SQL queries that I build in PowerQuery.
How ever I would like to code those in VBA.
But after internet search, I still  can not find my way to connect properly to the SQL tables.
I have problem in my connections string I suppose.
Please advice.

Attached is the PowerQuery querie.
Let me know please.

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("EU002VM0353"),
    EPV2P9028 = Source{[Name="EPV2P9053"]}[Data],
    dbo_vw_pbi_01_fact_inspection_state = EPV2P9053{[Schema="dbo",Item="vw_pbi_01_fact_inspection_state"]}[Data],

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_vw_pbi_01_fact_inspection_state, each ([QCF Is required] = true) and ([Is NA] = false) and ([WS status] = "Active")),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data directly from sql server to your excel sheet, you can use this piece of code:

```
'Define variables
Public con As Object, rs As Object, cmd As Object
Public Const provider As String = "SQLOLEDB"
Public Const server As String = "ServerName_or_IP_Adress"
Public Const database As String = "Database_Name"
Public Const serverUser As String = "ServerUser_(sa)"
Public Const serverPass As String = "xxx"
Public Const sheetName As String = "Query_Output_Sheet_Name"

' "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" reference must be selected
Private Sub Query()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(sheetName)
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    
    con.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=" & provider & ";" & _
        "Data Source=" & server & ";" & _
        "Initial Catalog=" & database & ";" & _
        "User ID=" & serverUser & ";" & _
        "Password=" & serverPass & ";" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" & _
        "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"
    
    con.Open
    
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Select * from TableName"

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600
    cmd.CommandText = Query
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)
    
    If rs.EOF = False Then ws.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Connection variables defined as public, so you can call them from other modules or userforms. You just need to fill variables and  sheet name (which you want to get the data)